# how do I make a function to find the mean of a function in scheme

Tags: scheme

```
((define (sum list)
(if(null? list)
   0
   (+(car list)(sum(cdr list)))))

(define (mean list)
  (if(null? list)
     0
    
     (/ (sum list) (length list))))
(mean (list 1 2 3 4))
```

so apparently the mean being returned is 2 1/2 but it should be 2 just 2 as 10/5 is 2 what should I do to make correct mean??

Comment: Where do you get 10/5 in that?

Comment: 1, 2, 3, 4 – four numbers, not five.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. The sum of `(list 1 2 3 4)` is `10` and that list has four elements, so the result will be `2 1/2`.

You should also add some spaces to increase readability and don't use function names for the naming of variables ([`list`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._list%29%29), in this case). The improved version will look like this:

```
(define (sum lst)
  (if (null? lst) 0
      (+ (car lst)
         (sum (cdr lst)))))

(define (mean lst)
  (if (null? lst) 0
      (/ (sum lst)
         (length lst))))
```

Test:

```
(mean (list 1 2 3 4))
=> 2 1/2
```

Note that you can also return the sum of the list like this:

```
> (apply + (list 1 2 3 4))
10
```